# How to retrieve all the nodes at any given level in a non-binary tree?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Level of the non binary tree is input to the method, and I need to print all the nodes present in that level. 
Note: The tree is Non-Binary tree.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

You could do a Breadth first search. Whenever distance is equal to level you print the node. When distance becomes greater than level you stop the search.